# Why does awaiting the second task invoke the first task?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

This Python 3.10 code

```
import asyncio
import time

async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)

async def main():
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(1, 'task 1'))
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(say_after(2, 'task 2'))

    print(f'Start at {time.strftime("%X")}')

    await t2

    print(f'End at {time.strftime("%X")}')

asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)
```

outputs this:

```
Start at 03:32:50
task 1
task 2
End at 03:32:52
```

I didn't await `t1` but it still runs.

Code is taken from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) and modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create_task` schedules a task to be executed by the event loop. It will be executed in the background if the event loop runs long enough, whether you await it or not.

Awaiting `t2` just happens to let the event loop run long enough to finish `t1`, too.

If you swap the `sleep` durations, you should not see the output from `t1`, because the main program finishes before it is done.